# How deal with child entites with unique attributes in JPA+Hibernate+Spring?

Tags: spring, jpa, unique, one-to-many, cascade

Saving a many-to-one association only works the first time.
How save father with appended child if child entries already exist and prevent the "Unique index or primary key violated" error message ?

Note: that the name attribute is unique!

The main program.

```
// This works 
            Car car1 = new Car();
            Car car2 = new Car();
            Car car3 = new Car();

            Model model1 = new Model();
            Model model2 = new Model();

            model1.setName("911");
            model2.setName("Vito");

            car1.setLicense("S-TU-123");
            car2.setLicense("S-GH-124");
            car3.setLicense("S-BN-123");

            car1.setModel(model1);
            car2.setModel(model2);
            car3.setModel(model1);

            carRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(car1, car2, car3));

            //// wont work because of "Unique index or primary key violated"

            Car car4 = new Car();
            Model model4 = new Model();

            car4.setModel(model4);

            model4.setName("911"); // <== exists in database already
            car4.setLicense("L-QQ-001");

            carService.save(car4);
```

model code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String license;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Model model;

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.getCars().add(this);
    }

    public void removeModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.getCars().add(null);
    }
}
```

car code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "models")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Model {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "model", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
        for (Car car : cars) {
            car.setModel(this);
        }
    }
}
```

car repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

model repository:

```
public interface ModelRepository extends JpaRepository<Model, Long> {
    Optional<Model> findByLicense(String license);
}
```

Comment: Are you, in all seriousness, asking how to store non-unique values in a unique column?

Comment: The user can insert data by REST call. e.g .: {"license": "S-BN-123", "model": {"name": "911"}}
It should be checked whether the unique value already exists or not. It will then be created or read out and linked to the car entity.

Comment: Well then, you just described what your code needs to do: first, it needs to check whether the value already exists, and only create a new `Model` if it doesn't (`Model model = modelRepository.findByName(name).orElseGet(() -> new Model(name))`)